# Material Date Picker Custom Styling

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components, material-components-android

i have used range date picker from google material with this library

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'

this is my code

```
     MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder =
            MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();

    CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());
    MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long,Long>> picker = builder.build();
    assert getFragmentManager() != null;
    picker.show(getFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

i want to custom the dialog picker change text field,make dialog not full screen etc..
how can i make all this modifications

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with  change text field?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti change save text, start date and end date text

Answer (score 30, accepted):

About the **fullscreen**.

The range picker should cover the entire screen (default = dialog for single date, fullscreen for range).
However you can change this behavior in your style.

You can use the **`setTheme`** method to apply a theme overlay:

```
//To apply a dialog
builder.setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar);
//To apply the fullscreen:
builder.setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen);
```

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.2.0-alpha01`.

**As alternative** you can add in your app theme the **`materialCalendarFullscreenTheme`** attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/CustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen</item>
</style>
```

where:

```
  <style name="CustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen"
      parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Custom_MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
  </style>
```

Here you can override the value with the **`android:windowFullscreen`** attribute:

```
  <style name="Custom_MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen"
      parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

---

**About the strings**.
Currently there isn't a method to change the strings.
The only existing method is **`builder.setTitleText`** to change the title.

However you can override all the existing strings in your project, but **this workaround can stop** to run in the next releases.
For example:

```
  <string name="mtrl_picker_save" description="Confirms the selection [CHAR_LIMIT=12]">....</string>
  <string name="mtrl_picker_text_input_date_range_start_hint" description="Label for the start date in a range selected by the user [CHAR_LIMIT=60]">...</string>
  <string name="mtrl_picker_text_input_date_range_end_hint" description="Label for the end date in a range selected by the user [CHAR_LIMIT=60]">...</string>
```

[image]

Here you can find [all the strings](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0-alpha02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/res/values/strings.xml) used by the material calendar in the `1.2.0-alpha02`.

Comment: thinks so much for your response, to disable full screen it work like charm, but about override string in my code how can i do that ?

Comment: @zakaria Just put in your strings.xml the items that you want to override as the sample above.

Comment: yes i fixed just copy paste String in your String file and change the value thinks for your help now it work

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you should play with styles. In your AppTheme add an item `materialCalendarTheme` with your custom style that inherits parent `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar`, and change the style.

1. Change text field - call `MaterialDatePicker.Builder` function `setTitleText()`
2. Make dialog not full screen - you can't change it for date range picker, the documentation says that it is fullscreen by default

> Mobile date range pickers allow selection of a range of dates. They
>   cover the entire screen.

Here's documentation https://material.io/components/pickers

Here's how I tweaked some colors to match my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendar</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendarButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendarButton</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendarTextButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendarButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">?themeTextColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendarTextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush">
    <item name="android:textColor">?themeTextColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="iconTint">?themeTextColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: When I set `android:textColor` in `ThemeMaterialCalendarButton`, it crashes an application.

Answer (score 5):

Changing between fullscreen and dialog version can be as easy as that:

**fullscreen**:

```
val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen).build()
```

**dialog**:

```
val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar).build()
```

Comment: It works. I had to upgrade the library to `'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'` from 1.1.0 so that `R.style....` was not highlighted as private property by Lint.

Comment: Can we apply our own `layout` file for the DatePicker fragment?

Answer (score 1):

While the posted answer totally work there seems to be no need to set the `materialCalendarTheme` globally - you can just set it to via the `MaterialDatePicker.Builder` and `setTheme(int themeResId)` method. Following an example how they do it in the [Material Design Catalog App](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/datepicker/DatePickerMainDemoFragment.java#L121).

```
val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().apply {
    context?.resolveOrNull(R.attr.materialCalendarTheme)?.let {
        setTheme(it)
    }
    setCalendarConstraints(getConstraints())
    }.build()
// ...
```

**resolveOrThrow** helper method:

```
fun Context.resolveOrNull(@AttrRes attributeResId: Int): Int? {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    if (theme.resolveAttribute(attributeResId, typedValue, true)) {
        return typedValue.data
    }
    return null
}
```

This way you DatePicker dialog won't be full screen but a regular dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by postfixNotation is correct but not entirely as he forgot to mention the package name where the style is available. I was scratching my head for about 30 mins to find that since its not directly available at R.style.... So here's the answer that will work out for all incase this happened to somebody else.

Changing between fullscreen and dialog version can be as easy as that:

**fullscreen**:

```
val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().setTheme(com.google.android.material.R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen).build()
```

**dialog**:

```
val picker =  MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().setTheme(com.google.android.material.R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar).build()
```