# How to cut(remove or hide or shrink) the header_title of Material dateRangePicker(Dialog) in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components-android

#### I want to remove the space on top

[image]

My style theme (stackOverFlow's user answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266415/13050313))

My code

```
fun clickDatePicker() {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_MaterailComponent)

        val local = Locale.KOREA
        Locale.setDefault(local)

        val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
        val picker = builder.build()
        picker.apply {
            addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selection: Pair<Long, Long>? ->
                // just my other logic
                selection?.first?.let { setYearMonthDate(it) }
                    ?.let { it1 -> firstAndSecondMap.put(0, it1) }
                selection?.second?.let { setYearMonthDate(it) }
                    ?.let { it1 -> firstAndSecondMap.put(1, it1) }
                filterDate()
                binding.duration = 0
            }
            show(supportFragmentManager, "picker")
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently (`1.1.0`,`1.2.0-beta01`,`1.3.0-alpha01`) there **isn't** a method to hide the header title.
It is only a workaround and it can stop working in the next releases.

In your theme overlay you can set the `visibility` of the HeaderTitle with:

```
   <style name="MaterialCalendarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/HeaderTitle_Hide</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HeaderTitle_Hide" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderTitle">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>
```

It is not enough. You have to override these dimens in your project.

```
<dimen name="mtrl_calendar_header_height">72dp</dimen>
<dimen name="mtrl_calendar_selection_text_baseline_to_top">58dp</dimen>
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!! thank you so much!! very clear!! (I use 1.1.0)

Comment: Is it possible to also remove the Start date-End date container?

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide Title and select date section
I tried adding

```
<dimen name="mtrl_calendar_header_height">0dp</dimen>
```

in dimens.xml

I'm using the following version of 'material':

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

[Header and Select date section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBk2R.png)

Result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLHJA.png)