# Date range picker overlaps phone's navigation buttons

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialdatepicker

I am currently using this version of the material library

`com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha02`

However, when I show a date range picker using the martial date picker, the picker overlaps the navigation buttons on my phone see image below:

[image: Screenshot from s22 Ultra]

Comment: maybe due to `fitsSystemWindows` set to true and transparent navigation bar

Answer (score 5):

The reason that it's overlapping with the navigation bar that the `MaterialDatePicker` [defaults to a full-screen](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/3b333ee8343dc0bde20d110a39ccc4654977eb23/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.java#L520) unless there is a customized style, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266415/9851608). But that is not what you want either as it will be like a floating dialog.

To fix this, you'd change the picker window to not fit its content view to the window insets by passing true to `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows`. [Please check documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge#lay-out-in-full-screen) for more clarification.

But, this also affects the top inset of the status bar, so now it will look like transparent; so you have to change its color to match with that of the picker head background.

Here is a demo:

```
val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().build()
picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "tag")

// Delay is used to give the dialog a chance to build as it would 
// return null unitl it's shown. MaterialDatePicker is a final class;
// so, this wouldn't be embedded in a custom extended class.
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    picker.dialog?.window?.apply {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(this, true)
        statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, 
                                    R.color.purple_500,  /* default dialog head color */
                                    null)
    }
}, 100)
```

[image]